# How to find SQL Server instance name and server name from the code behind using c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources() does not locate local SQL server 2008 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824188/sqldatasourceenumerator-instance-getdatasources-does-not-locate-local-sql-serv)

I am using code below to get all instance names and server names in my local machine, but it seems it is returning only one instance; how to get all list of instance name and server name in my local machine?

```
string myServer = Environment.MachineName;

DataTable servers = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();

for (int i = 0; i < servers.Rows.Count; i++)
{
        if (myServer == servers.Rows[i]["ServerName"].ToString()) 
        {
            if ((servers.Rows[i]["InstanceName"] as string) != null)
            {
                CmbServerName.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                CmbServerName.Items.Add(servers.Rows[i]["ServerName"] + "\\" + servers.Rows[i]["InstanceName"]);

            }
            else
            {
                CmbServerName.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                CmbServerName.Items.Add(servers.Rows[i]["ServerName"]);

            }
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Another way to get the installed instance names of sql server is to read your machine registry. It will fetch all the instances of sql from your local machine.

```
RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server");
            String[] instances = (String[])rk.GetValue("InstalledInstances");
            if (instances.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (String element in instances)
                {
                    if (element == "MSSQLSERVER")
                        Console.WriteLine(System.Environment.MachineName);
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine(System.Environment.MachineName + @"\" + element);

                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

Comment: Your code also returning only one instance name, more exactly it is returning only System.Environment.MachineName

Comment: @FirdavsKurbonov go to your registry and chk how many instances in your rigistry

Comment: It is showing only one MSSQLSERVER, but I know that there are also some instances in my machine like SQLEXPRESS;

Answer (score 1):

This might not be it, but worth a try. Is the [SQL Server Browser service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165724%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) running on your machine?

Answer (score 1):

[`GetDataSource()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator.getdatasources%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) retrieves all the instance visible from your machine. The *ServerName* is the name of the machine where the istance is hosted, and it appears you have only one istance on your machine.

What do you mean with the bolded part: "How to get all list of instance name and **server name in my local machine**" ? If you want to see every server visible from your machine you have to remove the *if statement*

```
if (myServer == servers.Rows[i]["ServerName"].ToString())
```

because there is only one server with your local machine name so you can't get any other server name.

Note that [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator.getdatasources%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) reports

> Due to the nature of the mechanism used by SqlDataSourceEnumerator to
>   locate data sources on a network, **the method will not always return a
>   complete list of the available servers, and the list might not be the
>   same on every call**. If you plan to use this function to let users
>   select a server from a list, make sure that you always also supply an
>   option to type in a name that is not in the list, in case the server
>   enumeration does not return all the available servers. In addition,
>   this method may take a significant amount of time to execute, so be
>   careful about calling it when performance is critical.

so it could be due to this problem.

Comment: even by removing if (myServer == servers.Rows[i]["ServerName"].ToString()) I do not get all instances; The interesting is that two codes give the different result; My code returns FIRDAVS/SQLEXPRESS and the code which Talha wrote give me different result FIRDAVS/MSSQLSERVER   I know that I have more than 2 instances in my machine, but the code is not showing me.

Comment: you have one Sql Server and one Sql Express? Are both started on your machine or one is stopped?

Comment: Yes I have sql server and sql express, both are running.

Comment: Try to create a new ODBC Data Source using Sql Server Provider, when you open the "Server" Combobox, how many istances do you see?

Comment: I did not understand, where to create it? In visual studio or SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: From the classic ODBC in windows. Or you could also try in Visual studio, just anywhere you can configure an SQL Connection. I suggest to avoid Management studio because, if i remember well, he saves used server so the test would not be correct.

Comment: Then i think this is due to the function itself. For some reason the list is not always complete as documented. i think you should work on another way to get there, like using the registry

Comment: One more thought: this function should use some network traffic, you could try to look for firewall configuration or port conflict between the istances

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am using the code from here, and it is working for me.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824188/sqldatasourceenumerator-instance-getdatasources-does-not-locate-local-sql-serv

Comment: so you removed the IF statement on server name

Comment: Not only, I just used their code. It is completely different method.

Comment: Well not exactly... It's more elegant using a foreach and the output is well  formatted, but both codes go through the same DataTable. However i'm glad you found a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

A alternative solution:

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.smoapplication.enumavailablesqlservers.aspx)