# How to Get Server name and instance name in c# and show in combobox

Tags: c#, database

Please Help me.
How to Get Server name and instance name in c# and show in combobox.

Comment: What server name and instance? question is not clear give more details

Comment: Please give more details in the question, it is almost impossible to determine what you want based on the information given.

Comment: check this.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162132.aspx

Comment: [Dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249306/how-to-find-sql-server-instance-name-and-server-name-from-the-code-behind-using)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in Sql Server you can use something like this:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Sql;

var instances = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();
foreach (DataRow instance in instances.AsEnumerable())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"ServerName: {instance["ServerName"]}; "+
       " Instance: {instance["InstanceName"]}");
}
```

More information about the `SqlDataSourceEnumerator` class you can find on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqldatasourceenumerator(v=vs.110).aspx).

### Note:

This class will look into the local network for servers, if your network is large then there might be a delay in acquiring the response. Also for the empty string instance name, that should be the default instance for that SQL Server.

You can get this information using the SMO too, if you want.

Comment: I am trying this but not working....it shows empty combobox 

SqlDataSourceEnumerator sd = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;

            DataTable table = sd.GetDataSources();

            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                combo_server.Items.Add(row["ServerName"].ToString() + "\\" + row["InstanceName"].ToString());
            }

Comment: Are your SQL servers in the same network as the machine you are running the code from?

Comment: sir i am trying on local machine.

Comment: Check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6t1z9x2(v=vs.110).aspx). And there is a section "Enumeration Limitations"

Answer (score 1):

Get Server name and instance name Add in combobox. This will take less time try it

```
 string ServerName = Environment.MachineName;
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView registryView = Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView.Registry64 : Microsoft.Win32.RegistryView.Registry32;
        using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey hklm = Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, registryView))
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey instanceKey = hklm.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL", false);
            if (instanceKey != null)
            {
                foreach (var instanceName in instanceKey.GetValueNames())
                {
                    if (instanceName == "MSSQLSERVER")
                    {
                        cmbServerName.Items.Add(ServerName);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cmbServerName.Items.Add(ServerName + "\\" + instanceName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the accepted answer but for those who have a SqlClient.SqlConnection already opened, you can retrieve the instance name from

```
    Dim c As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(sConnectionString)

    '   Get the database name and server

    SourceDatabase = c.Database
    SourceServer = c.DataSource
```

Sorry for the VB ;)