# Get list of database servers with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources() does not locate local SQL server 2008 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824188/sqldatasourceenumerator-instance-getdatasources-does-not-locate-local-sql-serv)

In SQL Server 2008, when I open the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I have to connect to a server.

First I select `Server Type` (like `Database Engine`), then server names are available.

Generally, there are server name's used recently. But if I go for `<Browse For More...>` I get a window with two tabs

1. Local Servers
2. Network Servers.

When I select `Network Servers`, there is a list of available servers on the network.

Now I want to know how can I do this myself in C# ? I just need to know, how can I get the list of network servers in my C# app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with:

```
DataTable dt = System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();
```

You will get DataTable with servernames and instancenames.

Answer (score 1):

I found this Link helpful, After Dejo give me the hint how to do this. This Link can be helpful for everyone. Atleast it helped me.

[SQL data source enumerator instance get data sources does not locate local SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6824188/sqldatasourceenumerator-instance-getdatasources-does-not-locate-local-sql-serv)