# C# get local network SQL Server instance name

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a problem with the SQL Server instance name on a local network, because I need the whole name (`serverName\instanceName`) and when a ask with this:

```
System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator instance = System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;

System.Data.DataTable table = instance.GetDataSources();

foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in table.Columns)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", col.ColumnName, row[col]);
    }
}
```

I only get back the server name and the instance name is blank (I know that if blank it means that it has a default value).

This is a sample output the local SQL Server (`student1`) is filled but the network versions isn't.

```
ServerName = STUDENT1
InstanceName = SQLEXPRESS2014
IsClustered = No
Version = 12.0.4100.1

ServerName = XYZ
InstanceName =
IsClustered =
Version =

ServerName = QWE
InstanceName =
IsClustered =
Version =
```

How can I get the whole name or some alternative solution for this?

Comment: maybe those servers don't have instances defined? It's not compulsory for a SQL server to be set up with instances.

Comment: You can check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13993652/2224701