# VB.NET: How can you get the SQL server name and instance name in Windows 10?

Tags: vb.net, windows-10

This startup form is used for getting the SQL Server name and instance name:

```
Private Sub GetServerList()

    Try
        Dim Server As String = String.Empty
        Dim instance As SqlDataSourceEnumerator = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance
        Dim cmbServers = New ComboBox
        Dim table As DataTable = instance.GetDataSources()
        For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
            Server = String.Empty
            Server = row("ServerName")
            If row("InstanceName").ToString.Length > 0 Then
                Server = Server & "\" & row("InstanceName")
            End If
            cmbServers.Items.Add(Server)
        Next

        cmbServers.SelectedIndex = cmbServers.FindStringExact(Environment.MachineName)
        My.Settings.ServerName = cmbServers.Text
        My.Settings.Save()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to the Server", "SMALLER", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The main problem is that no server name nor instance name is being displayed in the ComboBox, I've checked it myself using `Msgbox(cmbServers.Text)` the result is blank. While for other versions of Windows (7, 8, 8.1) there are no issues...

I've read a similar post regarding this as well, one of the solutions states that you must enable the SQL Server Browser service, I've turned the said service on, but still no luck...

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what *doesn't work* and show the relevant code from `CheckConnection()`.

Comment: If you've solved the [common problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6824322/11683) (e.g. firewall), it might be https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4494179f-2048-4efd-8f01-c994245b70a0/sqldatasourceenumeratorinstance-with-windows-10-does-not-return-any-servers?forum=winforms

Comment: You can disregard the "CheckConnection()" The main problem is that no server name nor instance name is being displayed in the combobox, I've checked it myself using Msgbox(cmbServers.Text) the result is blank. While for other versions of Windows (7, 8, 8.1) there are no issues, the code works perfectly for them. Sorry if my code confuses you.

Comment: You need to debug your code and compare the returned `ServerName` values against `Environment.MachineName`.  Why you would expect there to always be an expect match is pure folly.   Also, using a `ComboBox` as a data structure to hold a list a of strings is also very strange. A `List(Of String)` makes much more sense.